# Django - Reading from live Database, created by separate application

Tags: django, database, sqlite, django-models

I have an sqlite database located at `/home/pi/Desktop/Databsaes/data.db` and wish to access it from my `models.py` script.

To view table contents in a normal command prompt I would execute:

```
sqlite3
sqlite> .open data.db
sqlite> SELECT * from table1
```

I have been reading through this [official tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/queries/), but I do not understand how to access my local db and perform the above.

> In SQL terms, a QuerySet equates to a SELECT statement,

*... but how can I perform something of the sort directly in my `models.py` script?*

Models.py is still untouched:

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.db import models

# Create your models here
```

From what I am gathering, field lookups may be used, which specify arguments for `QuerySet` methods (such as `get()`).

**EDIT**

I followed this [tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/legacy-databases/) to import the database into Django.

However my question is: **Will new data added to this database by a separate process be visible from Django's side after the import?**

> If you do want to allow Django to manage the table’s lifecycle, you’ll need to change the managed option above to True (or simply remove it because True is its default value).

I don not know whether "manage the table's lifecycle" means to update the database with newer data once this is added.

Comment: What changes? You mean schema changes? No, they wouldn't be auto-imported. You will need to edit models.py yourself. Are you really making so many that this is a problem? Ideally, you would move management of the db into Django itself and make changes via migrations.

Comment: Unfortunately I am logging data from a sensor at a very fast rate (1000 times per minute), however I only need to access the database every 30 seconds. I was looking for a way to auto-update the database each time I need to read from it. If I were to move the db management into Django, can it (Django) handle such fast schema changes?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking here. Data added by your separate process wouldn't change the schema, and would be available immediately via Django.

Comment: I have a separate process logging data to a database every 30 seconds. I need to read from this databsae in Django and update my web page (also every 30 seconds). My question is how can I move the db management to Django without having to modify my separate process. Sorry for any thing which lacks clarity.

Comment: But like I say you don't need to do this if you are not changing the *structure* of your tables in your external process. Adding data won't change your schema. There is nothing else you need to do.

Comment: You are absolutely right ! Sorry for the confusion from my end. I will not be changing the structure of my tables, only adding data. That's why I was looking for a way to update my webpage when new data is added to the database by my separate process. I _edited_ my _edit_ above and am still not sure whether **new** data is auto-imported or not.

Comment: Data isn't "imported" at all. You're querying the same database. Any data that is there will be visible to Django.

Comment: You're right but the legacy database was intiially integrated with Django. Will any data added after the integration, from my separate process, be accessible from Django? Thanks

Comment: Once again, **yes**. The data is in the database. Django will query it. There is no importing going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the statement of `managed=False` might be the main point that confusing you. Here is the description on [`Model._meta.managed`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/options/#managed):

> If False, no database table creation or deletion operations will be performed for this model. This is useful if the model represents an existing table or a database view that has been created by some other means. This is the only difference when managed=False. All other aspects of model handling are exactly the same as normal. This includes

This means new migrations will not be generated (through `makemigrations`) for the modification of models schema with `managed=False`. This implies that you are telling Django, "I'm not going to change these model's schema through Django" (But through other way, maybe through another service).

Note that all we were talking about are just the effect on *schema changed*, which is nothing to do with your real data. After the link of your database and Django model has been established, just as @DanielRoseman's comments, any data that is there will be visible to Django on each query.

Since according to your statement the question is for *newly-added data*, the answer should be **yes**. But, if you were meaning that new tables are created through other service (not through the Django service above), of course you still have to add the corresponding model to Django (with `managed=False`) then you will be able to access data through Django.

Comment: As I understood it, no new tables are going to be created, only new data added. Was the link created correctly with the database by fcp? Since I was trying to achieve something of the sort too.